# installer updation using RPM

Tags: unix, installation, rpm, rpm-spec

I have an RPM package for my application and the path of the installation is /company/application/version.

I am finding this difficult as it is a unix platform and there is no registry concept.

I need few things to be clarified:

- How can i check the previous installed version number?

Every time I install my different version application all gets installed (i.e 2.5 and 2.6 both are considered as 2 different softwares because of the installation directory structure.)

- How can I stop the newer version when old is already installed?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8575531/719147

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the spec file, this is just shooting in the dark, but I would guess you are probably missing the 'Version' tag in your spec file.  See http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-tags.html.  In general, Maximum RPM is a good resource.